# Execution of Parallel Script from a single Cron Job

Tags: shell

How to execute a different `command/script` (Task-B) in a parallel mode, while the primary task `command/script` (Task-A) is exceeding the defined time window/period; which is mentioned in the `crontab` ?

@ Production environment, not having `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Your question is very unclear - please improve it else it is likely to get closed. What is command/script Task-B? What is command/script Task-A? What is the defined window? Who set it? What is in your crontab? What OS are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: `* * * * * /bin/timeout -h '{/path/to/task-b/script.sh}' 2 /path/to/task-a/script.sh`

Comment: If that's the correct answer to your question, please put it as an *answer* (rather than a *comment*) and accept it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am not sure, that's why I am asking ?